# Problema com css de slideshow

Tags: html, css

Quero deixar o slide com o formato da imagem abaixo.
Eu adiciono o `display:block` nas imagenss do meu slideshow, mas, não funciona!

[image: o modelo do meu slideshow]

```
HTML:
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slide">

    <div class="slide-1">
     <img src="img/01.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-2">
     <img src="img/img02.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-3">
     <img src="img/img02.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow{
    width:100%;
    max-width:980px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.slide{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}

.slide-1{
    width:75%;
    height:505px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-2{
    width:50%;
    height:250px;
    float:right;
}

.slide-3{
    width:50%;
    height:250px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Mas afinal, o que você quer fazer? Deixá-lo como na imagem?

Comment: Sim. Quero deixar igual a imagem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrija a porcentagem dos slides. 75% + 50% dá 125%.
Use `float: left` em todos os elementos.

```
.slide-1{
    width:75%;
    height:505px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-2{
    width:25%;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
}

.slide-3{
    width:25%;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
}
```

[» **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hnq2dvxm/2/)

Comment: Amigo eu coloquei tudo que vc mandou, mas, o width das imgs não fica igual ao do modelo do slide ! Se não for incomodo ?

Comment: Olha o link do JSFiddle que coloquei na resposta. Lá mostra o código funcionando. Tenta aí. Lembre-se de quando mexer no tamanho das imagens, também calcular a porcentagem das divs. Leve em consideração do seu 980px. Se é 75% a imagem maior deve ter 735px e as menores 245px de largura!

Comment: vlw me ajudou muito !!

Comment: ainda sou leigo na programação web !